# How to centralize DI code outside of lambda function.cs and instead into dedicated class for better separation of concerns

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function and running dotnet core. I want to use DI, however, I dont want to add DI container related code within the default function class, but instead in a separate file.

How can I do DI in a separate class?

Here is how to accomplish within the function class. However, I want to put this into dedicated class for better separation of concerns.

```
namespace SQSMessageProcessor
{
    public class Function
    {
        private ILambdaConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private IOrdersService OrderService { get; }
        public Function()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            Configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<ILambdaConfiguration>();
            OrderService = serviceProvider.GetService<IOrdersService>();
        }
        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<ILambdaConfiguration, LambdaConfiguration>();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IOrdersService, OrdersService>();
        }

        public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(SQSEvent sqsEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(Configuration.Configuration["hello"]);
            Console.WriteLine($"Message ID: {sqsEvent.Records[0].MessageId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Event Source: {sqsEvent.Records[0].EventSource}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Record Body Parsed:");

            var details = JObject.Parse(sqsEvent.Records[0].Body);
            Console.WriteLine(details);
            var order = details.ToObject<Order>();
            await OrderService.ProcessOrder(order);
            return $"Processed {sqsEvent.Records.Count} records.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your idea right, you can add an extension static class and make DI there

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddRabbitMq(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(RabbitMqOptions), service =>
        {
            //...
        });
    }
}
```

and then use it in your ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddRabbitMq();
}
```

Comment: Does ConfigureServices need to be in public class Function?

Comment: @jbooker Yes, it should be in class that specified by calling `WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseStartup<TStartup>` method. More information about Startup class and ConfigureServices method you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Can Lambda functions have a startup class? If so how does this startup class compared to ASP.net core web API startup class?

Comment: @jbooker So, your lambda handler contains in Function class, that is part of .net core web API app, right? So you can inject your dependencies in Startup class. This class already defined and exist in your web API project. It contains `ConfigureServices` method, where you can do DI.

Comment: "that is part of .net core web API app, right?" Um,  Im asking you! haha. I dont see the relationship between a lambda function and a web api at all. The only relationship is that lambda is using dotnet core.

Comment: Because you call `ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);` method in your constructor, you can define it wherever you want, just make sure you add namespace to your class

Comment: Ok, so can you speak to your comment on how webapi has anything to do with lambda?

Comment: I'm not realy into AWS lambda function, but you can deploy existed web api project into lambda function, [check this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/) for more